# Is there a way in which I can isolate a vertical slider from the rest of the website sections below?

Tags: html, css, slider, fullpage.js

I understand fullpage.js is solely used to build single page vertical slider orienated sites where the content of the site transitions from slide to slide going up or down respectively.

Having successfully implemented and somewhat customised the vertical slider into new website layout, I am unable to view the others sections of the website that come below it.

The vertical slider it seems prevents the rest of the html section blocks below it to appear. Its as if the vertical slider is saying: 'I AM THE WEBSITE'  ( ignores w/e the hell I place beneath it ).

Here is what we have:

```
<div id="fullpage">
<div class="slide" id="slide_1">
    <div class="slide_caption">
        <h1>This is slide 1</h1>
        <h4>slide 1 description</h4>
        <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slide" id="slide_2">
    <div class="slide_caption">
        <h1>This is slide 2</h1>
        <h4>slide 2 description</h4>
        <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slide" id="slide_3">
    <div class="slide_caption">
        <h1>This is slide 3</h1>
        <h4>slide 3 description</h4>
        <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slide" id="slide_4">
    <div class="slide_caption">
        <h1>This is slide 4</h1>
        <h4>slide 4 description</h4>
        <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<section class="full_width_container" id="home_container_1">
<!-- extra mark up for other stuff like latest products etc -->
</section>

<section class="full_width_container" id="home_container_2">
<!-- extra mark up for other stuff like news etc -->
</section>

<section class="full_width_container" id="home_container_3">
<!-- extra mark up for other stuff like testimonials etc -->
</section>

<section class="full_width_container" id="home_container_4">
<!-- extra mark up for blog post links -->
</section>

<footer>
<!-- extra mark up for footer items -->
</footer>
```

My question is - how the hell do I get the other sections below,  i.e home_container_1,  home_container_2, home_container_3 to show up ?

I tried applying overflow-y:scroll !important; on body whilst applying overflow-y:hidden on fullpage but it didn't quite work.

If somebody could point me in the right direction in terms of whats happening I would appreciate it no end.

Comment: Please show your output with fullpage.js code.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:  IF Anybody ends up having this problem,  the issue is 99.999% related to not including the DOCTYPE html declarative.

grrrrr @ this schoolboy error.  Why, despite so many years of web dev am I making these kind of idiotic mistakes :| ?  Alvaro the author of fullpage.js clearly mentioned this in his docs,  'make sure to include DOCTYPE html declarative else the heights wont work properly..'

So there you have it folks, the issue was the above.

Now the vertical slider stays put,  takes up 100vh of the screen and if you use the mouse scroll it scrolls the ENTIRE content in the viewport so you can view whats beneath the slider (the other website sections).